# how to solve the error " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'changePage' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, eclipse, cordova

I am just a beginner in phonegap as well as in javascript so while making a simple app for example, i wrote the following code in the index.html head and my main.js file is not getting included while i run the code. I hope anyone could help me out with the problem.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
            <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>Auth Demo</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
            <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="assests/www/main.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body onload="init()">
            <div id="loginPage" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Welcome to Phonegap</h1>
            </div>  
            <div data-role="content"> 
                <form id="loginForm">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                        <label for="username">Username:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                        <label for="password">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value=""    placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>
                   <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submitButton">
                </form>

            </div>

            <script>
                $("#loginPage").live("pageinit", function(e) {
                   checkPreAuth();
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

here is the main.js file code as well.I just want only a particular login id to be valid.

```
   function init() {
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceReady, true);
   delete init;
 }

  function checkPreAuth() {
   console.log("checkPreAuth");
 var form = $("#loginForm");
  if(window.localStorage["username"] != undefined && window.localStorage["password"] !=    undefined) {
    $("#username", form).val(window.localStorage["username"]);
    $("#password", form).val(window.localStorage["password"]);
     navigator.notification.alert("You entered a username and password");
     handleLogin();
    }
    }

     function handleLogin() {
   var form = $("#loginForm");    
    //disable the button so we can't resubmit while we wait
     $("#submitButton",form).attr("disabled","disabled");
     var u = $("#username", form).val();
    var p = $("#password", form).val();
   var str1 = "burden123";
   var str2 = "game1234";

  var n1 = str1.localeCompare(u);
    var n2 = str1.localeCompare(p);
if(u != '' && p!= '') {
    $.post("http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/demos/2011/nov/10/service.cfc?  method=login&returnformat=json", {username:u,password:p}, function(res) {
        if(n1==0 && n2==0) {
                 $.mobile.changePage("some.html");
            } else {
            navigator.notification.alert("Your login failed", function() {});
        }
        $("#submitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
    },"json");
  } else {
    navigator.notification.alert("You must enter a username and password", function()  {});
    $("#submitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
 }
  return false;
}

   function deviceReady() {
  console.log("deviceReady");
$("#loginPage").on("pageinit",function() {
    console.log("pageinit run");
    $("#loginForm").on("submit",handleLogin);
    checkPreAuth();
});
$.mobile.changePage("#loginPage");
   }
```

Comment: Follow the same pathing as the rest of the files included. Change `assets/www/main.js` to `main.js`. This is the same as any other website type project, relative pathing applies. Since `index.html` and `main.js` are in the same directory, you call it by name. Additionally if you place `main.js` in `www/js` directory, you would call it with `js/main.js`. Hope that helps

Comment: Are you getting any console log in log cat or try doing `alert("Function called");` on start of each function and check anything is happening or not.

Comment: yeah..i am getting web console its showing "$ is not defined". So how should i define it now?

Comment: It means jquery is not included. try the latest version of jquery and run.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Now I am getting a new error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'changePage' of undefined". How should i tackle that?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="assests/www/main.js"></script>
```

this line in your code should be changed to

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>
```

as main js is in same folder of index.html page.

Comment: Change the way you included the files. 
1.js/jquery-1.7.min.js 2.jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.js 3. main.js 4. cordova-2.7.0.js

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="assests/www/main.js"></script>
```

in above check you path in src also try putting it above and place a alert at top in main.js

check if all scripts above this is including or not.

Thanks